# Redemption can't send mail from mailbox Exchange 2016

Tags: vb6, outlook-redemption

I have multi mailboxs connecting into one domain.

My machine have Redemption version 5.22 with Outlook 2013.

The mailboxs from serveur Exchange 2013 can login and send the mails. But the mailbox Exchange 2016 can just login and can't send mail because of the code :

> -2147467259,Could not resolve the message recipients

This is the code to login. Both of them are logged on.

```
RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox O365@abc.fr, rapport.groupe.abc.fr 
RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox Exchange2013@abc.fr, rapport.groupe.abc.fr
RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox EXCH_2016@abc.fr, rapport.groupe.abc.fr
```

The mail has same destination.

Do I miss some installation on the machine ?

Comment: Are you getting a particular error when you try to send?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : yes, RDOMail raise a error code -2147467259 with the message "Could not resolve the message recipients". But the mail destimation works fine

Comment: What are the recipient names you are trying to send to? Are they SMTP addresses or names that are supposed to be resolved to GAL objects?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I used the debug version and I had a log file sent to you by mail. Can you look at it pls ? Thanks you for your help